# Highcharts, influxdb and nodejs, how to display data of influxdb in highcharts using influxdb-nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts, influxdb

I have a influxdb database and i would like to display its datas into a chart using highchart.

To do so, I'm taking the data from the database with :

- https://github.com/vicanso/influxdb-nodejs

  ```
  var time;
  var valeur;

  const Influx = require('influxdb-nodejs');
  const client = new Influx('http://127.0.0.1:8086/aTimeSeries');
  //query last value

  client.queryRaw('select * from "valeurs" group by * order by desc limit 1')
    .then((data) => {
          time = Date.parse(data.results[0].series[0].values[0][0]);
          valeur = data.results[0].series[0].values[0][1];

          console.info("[" + time + "," + valeur + "]");
    }).catch(console.error);

  var http = require('http');

  http.createServer(function (req, res) {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/json'});
      res.write("[" + time + "," + valeur + "]");
      res.end();
  }).listen(8080);
  ```

Then to display it, I try to use the example provide by Highcharts :

- https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <title>Highcharts Example</title>


          <!-- 1. Add these JavaScript inclusions in the head of your page -->
          <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
          <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>


          <!-- 2. Add the JavaScript to initialize the chart on document ready -->
          <script>
          var chart; // global

          /**
           * Request data from the server, add it to the graph and set a timeout to request again
           */
          function requestData() {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:8080/', 
                  success: function(point) {
                      var series = chart.series[0],
                          shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

                      // add the point
                      chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

                      // call it again after one second
                      setTimeout(requestData, 1000);  
                  },
                  cache: false
              });
          }

          $(document).ready(function() {
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                  chart: {
                      renderTo: 'container',
                      defaultSeriesType: 'spline',
                      events: {
                          load: requestData
                      }
                  },
                  title: {
                      text: 'Live random data'
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      type: 'datetime',
                      tickPixelInterval: 150,
                      maxZoom: 20 * 1000
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      minPadding: 0.2,
                      maxPadding: 0.2,
                      title: {
                          text: 'Value',
                          margin: 80
                      }
                  },
                  series: [{
                      name: 'Random data',
                      data: []
                  }]
              });     
          });
          </script>

      </head>
      <body>

          <!-- 3. Add the container -->
          <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      </body>
  ```

But as it's working with PHP, I had a lot of little issues, so I tried to switch in nodejs.

```
[1523957858507,40]
```

My nodejs file display the right data, the same way as my PHP file was doing it.

What i want is that my index html take the data from localhost:8080 where my JS send a json array.

thanks for your help

Comment: But we do not understand what you do not understand from what you did not understand.

Comment: What i want is that my index html take the data from http://localhost:8080 where my JS send a json array.

Comment: Can you add an example of what is being returned in your ajax call? In other words, the value for the `point` variable on your `success` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this, after making my own solution :') . But this one is much easier.

[visualizing-influxdb-data-with-highcharts](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/visualizing-data-with-highcharts/)